# Heroku reattach a deprovisioned portgres database ( Hobby-Basic )

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have unintentionally detached a Hobby-Basic postgres database from my application. Is there any way I can recover the database or the database backup?

I was able to get the database url by using heroku release:info command.

Answer (score 1):

We reached out to heroku support team and they reattached the detached db from their end.